# Unable to style custom scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I would like to have a custom scrollbar on one of my div, I have tried doing so by:

```css
#dropdow_list_outcome::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

#dropdow_list_outcome::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#dropdow_list_outcome::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#dropdow_list_outcome::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000; 
}
```

```html
<div id="outcomeDiv" style="position: absolute;top: 15%;left: 18%;height: 275px;width: 220px;display: block;z-index: 1;border: 1px solid #EEF6FB;border-radius:5px; background: #ffffff; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">

  <input id="outcome_Input" onkeyup="filterFunction()" type="text" style="position:relative; width:95%; border:1px solid #E5E5E5;font-family:roboto;font-size: 11px; margin-left:2.5%;margin-top:1%;border-radius:5px;"/>

  <img src="images/searchicon.png" style="position:absolute; left:88%;top:2%;height:16px;">

  <div id="dropdow_list_outcome" class="scrollbar" style="position: relative;width:95%;height: 90%;margin-left:2.5%;margin-top:1%;overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I populate `dropdow_list_outcome` dynamically,  but it still shows traditional scrollbar.

Comment: I tried using your code and populated a static list on the dropdow_list_outcome. It seems to be working on my end.

Comment: I think some other piece of code is not letting my custom scrollbar styles to appear. Can you possibly have any idea that which properties can override this CSS for custom scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

**A brief history of styling scrollbars:**

1. It used to be a thing only Internet Explorer could do (ancient versions) with stuff like -ms-scrollbar-base-colour. These do not exist anymore.
2. Then WebKit-based browser engines got on board with stuff like::-WebKit-scrollbar. That’s what this Alamanac entry mostly covers, as it works across the Safari/Chrome landscape today.
3. Standards have finally gotten involved, and those styling options are covered by un-prefixed properties like scrollbar-colour and scrollbar-width.

Follow these article. The answer is here:
Visit :
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/
https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Examples :
[Codepen 01][1]
[Codepen 02][2]
[1]: https://codepen.io/GhostRider/pen/GHaFw
[2]: https://codepen.io/rsp/pen/rfuxw

*Happy Coding!*

Answer (score 0):

you can simply take off the id that you are giving and use it directly.

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
 background: #b30000; 
}
```

also, you can check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_scrollbar).

Comment: I have created a simple project with vanilla js and I created that scroll bar, check it out it might help you. https://github.com/Draven-for-Websites/NetDraven

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with different browsers?
Be sure to use chrome, edge or safari to view results since firefox does not seem to display changes to styles unless over version 91.